# Show external mysql database data in webform field

Tags: webforms

External database. - I want to allow drupal webform users to choose data from an external mysql database table. They would have the option to choose a region and an associated locality when completing the webform. What is the best way to expose this data in webform?

I have created a view using the entity reference but can't seem to expose this in the form field? 
What is the simplest

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select) module.
But it works for D7 only.